# Oracle.DataAccess references break everytime that I get latest from TFS using VS2015

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015, tfs, .net-4.0, data-access

I am currently using Oracle.DataAccess (v2.112.3.0) as a reference in my Visual Studio 2015 project. I am working on a team project, so I get the latest version quite often to ensure my code is up to date. My problem is that every time I get latest from TFS my Oracle.DataAccess references break.  The only way that I can seem to get them to work again is if I remove them and then reinstall them using the Reference Manager in VS2015. Does anyone have any idea as to what could possibly be causing them to keep breaking?

Thanks. (P.S. I am new to Stack Overflow so sorry if my question isn’t exactly written the best way).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Consider [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41385887/edit)-ing your question to improve it.

Comment: my guess is that you're updating your main project file (csproj) and someone else was using different settings (x86 vs 64, different target framework, etc).  Also make sure your ODAC version is same as others or as expected.

Comment: Did you check the history of your project to see if there is anyone updated the reference?

Answer (score 0):

Even when everything is clean and tidy, Visual Studio will occasionally decide it can't find a file that's right under its nose, or that a file somewhere else on your system looks prettier, and it will break the reference. But this should not occur every time you check in.

Just as comment suggested, first make sure that you didn't move projects around or rename folders etc. Also make sure your ODAC version is same as others or as expected.

Another way is creating a new project to see if this error still exist.